# Time-based event possible on AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance that contains a table with the following columns:

```
- user_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
- device_id VARCHAR(255)
- start_time TIMEZONE
- end_time TIMEZONE
```

I want to call [this](https://docs.jumpcloud.com/api/2.0/index.html#tag/Systems/operation/graph_systemAssociationsPost) api that uses `device_id` and `user_id` for the path parameter and body respectively whenever `datetime.now()` is equal to `end_time`. Is it possible to do so or do I have to poll the database every x period?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL cannot do this.

The closest capability is [Schedule jobs with pg_cron on your Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL or Amazon Aurora for PostgreSQL databases | AWS Database Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-jobs-with-pg_cron-on-your-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-or-amazon-aurora-for-postgresql-databases/).

You will need to write a program outside of PostgreSQL to call the API.